# use single erb template for different files in a single puppet manifest

Tags: templates, puppet, erb

i like to use a single erb template to create different files. Here is my erb.

```
# managed by puppet
# changes will be overwritten
#
<% if (@tanuki_ssl != nil) -%>
# config include
# ssl section for trust and key stores
#
<% unless @tanuki_ssl['truststore_path'].nil? -%>
wrapper.java.additional.940=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<%= @tanuki_ssl['truststore_path'] %>
<% end -%>
<% unless @tanuki_ssl['truststore_pass'].nil? -%>
wrapper.java.additional.941=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<%= @tanuki_ssl['truststore_pass'] %>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>
<% if (@tanuki_proxy != nil) -%>
# config include
# proxy section
#
wrapper.java.additional.951=-Dhttp.proxySet=true
wrapper.java.additional.952=-Dhttp.proxyHost=<%= @tanuki_proxy['host'] %>
wrapper.java.additional.953=-Dhttp.proxyPort=<%= @tanuki_proxy['port'] %>
wrapper.java.additional.954=-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=<%= @tanuki_proxy['exceptions'].join('|') %>|<%= @ipaddress %>|<%= @hostname %>
wrapper.java.additional.955=-Dhttps.proxySet=true
wrapper.java.additional.956=-Dhttps.proxyHost=<%= @tanuki_proxy['host'] %>
wrapper.java.additional.957=-Dhttps.proxyPort=<%= @tanuki_proxy['port'] %>
wrapper.java.additional.958=-Dhttps.nonProxyHosts=<%= @tanuki_proxy['exceptions'].join('|') %>|<%= @ipaddress %>|<%= @hostname %>
<% end -%>
```

In my puppet manifest i wrote two file resources:

```
if $tanuki_hash['ssl_enabled'] {

  $tanuki_ssl = $tanuki_hash['ssl']

  file { "${tanuki_path}/${dirname}/conf/940-ssl.inc":
    content  => template('profile/app/wrapper.inc.erb'),
  }
}

if $tanuki_hash['proxy_enabled'] {

  if $tanuki_hash['override_system_proxy'] {
    $tanuki_proxy=$tanuki_hash['proxy']
  } else {
    $tanunki_proxy=$proxy_hash
  }

  file { "${tanuki_path}/${dirname}/conf/950-proxy.inc":
    content  => template('profile/app/wrapper.inc.erb'),
  }
}
```

I i run puppet now i get a file 940-ssl.incl with expected content. Only the first if section will be interpretet.

But file 950-proxy.inc have ssl part too.

So, how i can pass only the needed variable for each file?

Cheers

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find another approach which work for me. I created a define:

```
define tools::app::tanuki::include (
  Hash $property_hash      = {},
  String $include_template = 'tools/app/tanuki/wrapper.inc.erb',
  String $include_filename = $title,
){
  if $property_hash != {} {
    file { $include_filename:
      content  => template($include_template),
    }
  }
}
```

And in my puppet manifest i changed the code as followed:

```
if $tanuki_hash['ssl_enabled'] {

  $include_ssl = { type => 'ssl' }
  $tanuki_ssl_hash = merge($tanuki_hash['ssl'],$include_ssl)

  tools::app::tanuki::include { "${tanuki_path}/${dirname}/conf/940-ssl.inc":
    property_hash    => $tanuki_ssl_hash,
  }
}

if $tanuki_hash['proxy_enabled'] {

  $include_proxy = { type => 'proxy' }

  if $tanuki_hash['override_system_proxy'] {
    $tanuki_proxy=$tanuki_hash['proxy']
    $tanuki_proxy_hash = merge($tanuki_hash['proxy'],$include_proxy)
  } else {
    $tanunki_proxy=$proxy_hash
    $tanuki_proxy_hash = merge($proxy_hash,$include_proxy)
  }

  tools::app::tanuki::include { "${tanuki_path}/${dirname}/conf/950-proxy.inc":
    property_hash    => $tanuki_proxy_hash,
  }
}
```

So i can define different includes with on erb, which i modified a little bit.

```
# managed by puppet
# changes will be overwritten
#
<% if (@property_hash['type'] == 'ssl') -%>
# config include
# ssl section for trust and key stores
#
<% unless @property_hash['truststore_path'].nil? -%>
wrapper.java.additional.940=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<%= @property_hash['truststore_path'] %>
<% end -%>
<% unless @property_hash['truststore_pass'].nil? -%>
wrapper.java.additional.941=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<%= @property_hash['truststore_pass'] %>
<% end -%>
<% elsif (@property_hash['type'] == 'proxy') -%>
# config include
# proxy section
#
wrapper.java.additional.951=-Dhttp.proxySet=true
wrapper.java.additional.952=-Dhttp.proxyHost=<%= @property_hash['host'] %>
wrapper.java.additional.953=-Dhttp.proxyPort=<%= @property_hash['port'] %>
wrapper.java.additional.954=-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=<%= @property_hash['exceptions'].join('|') %>|<%= @ipaddress %>|<%= @hostname %>
wrapper.java.additional.955=-Dhttps.proxySet=true
wrapper.java.additional.956=-Dhttps.proxyHost=<%= @property_hash['host'] %>
wrapper.java.additional.957=-Dhttps.proxyPort=<%= @property_hash['port'] %>
wrapper.java.additional.958=-Dhttps.nonProxyHosts=<%= @property_hash['exceptions'].join('|') %>|<%= @ipaddress %>|<%= @hostname %>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to pass different variables to the ERB `template()` function, so I think you need to either:

1. Use the [epp() function](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/function.html#epp) with the [Embedded Puppet syntax](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_template_epp.html) instead of ERB, which lets you pass different local variables into the template when calling it.
2. Use different templates or different scopes. Rendering the same template within the same scope should typically render the same result, which is what you're trying to work against.